# May I link to my own Github project which is related to what I did after resolving my issue?

Tags: support

### Summary

In a [weird partition creation issue where GParted didn't think my SSD was a block device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679148/how-do-i-get-mkntfs-to-recognize-an-ssd-as-a-block-device), I eventually solved the issue and continued to my original goal: cloning a partition on a failing device into that new one. However, I have a lot of lost sectors. I decided to make a Python app on Github which will take the list of sectors (or raw log output from one or more common clone tools) and return a list of filenames.

### Question

Would this link be appropriate (since it's mine) and on topic (since it's not strictly part of the problem / resolution)?

---

- **Pro:** I think it's interesting to the original question and would have potential value to readers. It would also be an insignificant portion of the total question text.
- **Con:** It is really the "next step" from my question and not related to the specific question.

Comment: I overlooked your question at first; if the scope of your question and the scope of your GitHub project clearly differ, like it seems to be, it would be pretty unuseful to link the two; if you think your GitHub project is interesting and you'd like to share it, you should rather post an answer to a related question, if existing, or [post a question / answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) mentioning the exact issue you had and how you solved it.